# How to retrieve transaction from Hyperledger fabric network for Audit?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, ibm-blockchain

I would like to retrieve all transactions from the Hyperledger fabric netwrok for assurance. Please guide me to how retrieve transactions from all the peers to validate and completness of the transactions ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on your business requirement. For audit purpose, it's more likely you want to know transactions about a specific asset(key/value). You can query history of a specific key using the [GetHistoryForKey() shim API](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/77c3aa6ce5b0cfba93bfda009095886dbcadff91/core/chaincode/shim/interfaces.go). A transactionId is contained in the response. Then you can query the detail by the transactionId.

In addition, there are some query apis provided from the Fabric SDKS. For instance, the [NodeSDK](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node). In the Channel class, there are a bunch of apis like queryInfo, queryBlockByID, queryBlock, and queryTransaction etc. The [fabcar sample](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.2/fabcar) provides some NodeJS code you can follow up to create your own queries.

Finally, you can also inspect the ledgers (file based) directly from peer node. By default the path is /var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/chains, within which there are ledger files per channel. To inspect the files, you may need to investigate the [FileLedger impl](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.2/common/ledger/blockledger/file/impl.go). With some initialization work, you can inspect every block, the hash, the transactions and the Read/Write sets in detail. Hope this is helpful to you.